# Unexpected end of file in GLSL fragment shader

Tags: c++, glsl, shader, vertex

I'm just working on some per fragment lighting, working in visual studio 2010 C++ and using GLSL, and for some reason, only this fragment shader is having issues, I have pass through fragment shaders that work, and all of my vertex shaders work, so it's something to do with this specific guy. Basically my shader looks like this:

```
#version 120

varying vec3 normal;
varying vec3 lightDir;
varying vec4 ambient;
varying vec4 diffuse;

void main()
{
float NdotL = max(dot(lightDir,normalize(normal)),0.0);
gl_FragColor = vec4((NdotL * diffuse.rgb + ambient.rgb),  gl_FrontMaterial.diffuse.a);
}
```

Does anybody have any ideas to help? As I said, I already load multiple shaders into the program, but only this guy doesn't work

EDIT: Switched the vec3 to a float, still getting the same issue. HALP!

Comment: You can't change a question that invalidates the answer you accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dot(lightDir,normalize(normal))`  is the dot product. So it returns a scalar.

`max(scalar, scalar)` also evaluates to a scalar.

Therefore:

```
vec3 NdotL = max(dot(lightDir,normalize(normal)),0.0);
```

Attempts to assign a scalar to a vector. Which is invalid.

So what you probably wanted was:

```
float NdotL = max(dot(lightDir,normalize(normal)),0.0);
gl_FragColor = vec4((NdotL * diffuse.rgb + ambient.rgb),  gl_FrontMaterial.diffuse.a);
```

Comment: I tried that, still getting the same issue, any other solutions?

Comment: Having turned the `varying`s into variables, `NdotL` into a `float` and `gl_FrontMaterial.diffuse.a` into a constant, your code ran fine through the GLSL sandbox at http://www.mrdoob.com/projects/glsl_sandbox/ so I don't immediately have any other ideas — though some GLSL implementations require a newline at the end of the file; do you have one of those?

Comment: I did, thank you though sir, gonna just break this laptop instead of fixing it >.<

Comment: ....I didn't put the file in the resource folder. I'm the worst at this game.